# HDFS append in 0.23.5 using libhdfs

Tags: hadoop, append, hdfs

I am trying to append to a hdfs file on ver 0.23.5. I have set the property dfs.support.append to true in hdfs-site.xml. I am getting the following error when calling hdfsWrite() saying append is not supported.

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not supported
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.append(ChecksumFileSystem.java:345)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.append(FileSystem.java:1046)
Call to org.apache.hadoop.conf.FileSystem::append((Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream;) failed!`

I checked past literature on append in hdfs. Looks like append should work in 0.23.5.

I am able to insert and read. The problem is when I try to open for O_APPEND and write to the file. Here is the sample code -

```
int append(char *filepath, char *data, int size)
{
   hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("default", 0);
   int openFlags = O_WRONLY | O_APPEND;
   hdfsFile fdData = hdfsOpenFile(fs, filepath, openFlags, 0, 0, 0);
   if (!fdData) 
     return -1;
   if (hdfsWrite(fs, fdData, data, size) == -1)
     return -1;
   hdfsCloseFile(fs, fdData);

   return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something?

thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code? This will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Code posted. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

FSDataOutputStream doesn't support the append method.  Here's the relevant source:

```
  public FSDataOutputStream append(Path f, int bufferSize, Progressable progress) throws IOException {
    throw new IOException("Not supported");
  }
```

You'll notice that its super class FileSystem notes that append is an optional method.